# aggregating into nested groups in mongo

Tags: mongodb

Can Mongo aggregate this data:

```
cat     type     subtype   count
 A       aa           1       10
 A       aa           2       20 
 A       ac           4       15 
 B       ac           3       30 
 C       aa           3       40 
 C       aa           5       50 
 D       ac           6       60 
 D       aa           2       70
```

into a documents that look like the following:

```
   {
     'A': {
            'count': 45,
            'types': [
                {'type': 'aa', count:'30'},
                {'type': 'ac', count:'15'},
            ]
     },
     'B': {
            'count': 30,
            'types': [
                {'type': 'ac', count:'30'},
            ]
     },
     'C': {
            'count': 90,
            'types': [
                {'type': 'ac', count:'90'},
            ]
     },
     'D': {
            'count': 130,
            'types': [
                {'type': 'ac', count:'60'},
                {'type': 'aa', count:'70'},
            ]
     }
  }
```

Basically, created nested groups first by `type` and then by `cat` while running the total of `count` at each grouping level (if anyone's familiar with D3, that's what its `rollup` function with multiple keys can do).

Comment: Short answer YES! but why are you using your data as a key?

Comment: because this data will be used for lookups

Comment: I don't think that you need to do this. I suggest you change your structure like this: `{'name': 'A', 'count': 45, 'types': [{'type': 'aa', count:'30'}, {'type': 'ac', count:'15'} ] }`

Comment: but I still need to a nested grouping by `type`.  And how to do this is really the rub, not the output format.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this after realizing that I can have multiple $group commands in a pipeline.  The first $group is aggregating by `(cat, type)` and the second $group is aggregating the results from the first by `(cat)`.  Something along the lines of:

```
db.mycollection.aggregate([
   {
      $group: {
         _id: {'cat':'$cat','type':'$type'},
         'total': {$sum: $count}
      }
   },
   {
      $group: {
         _id: $_id.cat,
         types: {$push: {type: $_id.type, total: $total}},
         total: {$sum: $total}
      }
   },
   {
      $project: {
        _id: 0,
        cat: $_id.cat
        types: 1,
        total: 1
      }
   }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to fix Dmrity's own answer, as there are some various typos in it:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        cat  : "$cat",
        type : "$type"
      },
      total: {
        $sum: "$count"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.cat",
      types: {
        $push: {
          type: "$_id.type",
          total: "$total"
        }
      },
      total: {
        $sum: "$total"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      cat: "$_id",
      types: 1,
      total: 1
    }
  }
])
```